# MultiSelectList doesnt make items selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with a multiselectlist, if I hover dropObjectcategories in debug-mode it contains 4 items that should be selected.

```
List<int> selectedObjectcategoryIDs = new List<int>();

foreach (Objectcategory item in bo.Objectcategories)
{
    selectedObjectcategoryIDs.Add(item.ObjectcategoryID);
}

MultiSelectList dropObjectcategories = new MultiSelectList(_bs.GetObjectcategories(), "ObjectcategoryID", "ObjectcategoryName", selectedObjectcategoryIDs);
```

still it gets rendered without any items selected like this:

```
<select id="dropObjectcategories" multiple="multiple" name="dropObjectcategories"><option value="3">Airplanes</option><option value="10">Cars</option><option value="8">Computers</option><option value="9">Thingies</option></select>
```

what might be wrong here?

/M

Comment: I have stried to make it List<string> instead but same result

Comment: What is the type of _bs.GetObjectcategories()? Make sure that "ObjectcategoryID" is of the same type as items in selected list.

Comment: _bs.GetObjectcategories() is: IQueryable<Objectcategory> and ObjectcategoryID is an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
var selectedObjectcategoryIDs =
  from oc in bo.Objectcategories
  select oc.ObjectcategoryID;

MultiSelectList dropObjectcategories = new MultiSelectList(_bs.GetObjectcategories(), "ObjectcategoryID", "ObjectcategoryName", selectedObjectcategoryIDs);
```

Does it work?

Comment: nopes :( now I didnt even get count >0 selected items in debug mode

Comment: Do bo.Objectcategories containt any elements? If it doesn't, what do you want to be selected?